# Selenium Webdriver Java: Unable to perform click operation by Actions in Chrome

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver(Java) for my Automation. For one of my use-case, I need to click based on co-ordinates. I am using following code to perform this operation:

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveByOffset(236, 92).click().perform();
```

Above code is working perfectly in Firefox(Gecko driver). But with Chrome driver, it is not working. Any idea?
Is there any other way to perform this.

Comment: act.moveByOffset(236, 92).click().build().perform();

Comment: Already tried this. Didn't work.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try what Santosh has suggested

```
act.moveByOffset(236, 92).click().build().perform();
```

However, this should not make much of a difference as the perform() already contains the build action but this might be a workaround for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you can locate the webelement, you can use JavaScript to perform the click this way:

```
JavaScriptExecutor js = (driver)JavaScriptExecutor;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```